# How can i give limit in django?

Tags: django

I'm making a project  and want to use limit for fetch data how can i use limit if there are any function or any way i can give limit to my fetching data

i expect the output of (2019, 12, 27)(2019, 6, 30) to be (2019, 12, 27) but it fetching all records

```
def maintenancefunction(request): #maintenance page function
    if 'user' not in request.session:
        return redirect('/login')
    else:
        if request.session.has_key('user'):
            abc=request.session['user']

            today = date(2019,1,1)                        # today= date.today.().strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
            next_date=today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            lastdate= today + timedelta(days=180)
            new_date= lastdate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

            duedate=maintanance_table.objects.values_list('maintanance_todate').filter(user_email=abc).order_by('maintanance_todate').reverse()
            #         # newduedate=duedate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            print("DueDate:",duedate)
            checkstatus=maintanance_table.objects.filter(user_email=abc).filter(maintanance_status="PAID").order_by('maintanance_todate').reverse()
            if checkstatus:

                lastdate = lastdate + timedelta(days=180)
                new_date = lastdate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

            else:
                lastdate=lastdate
                new_date= lastdate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                return render(request,"maintenance.html", {'abc':abc,'new_date':new_date})
        else:
            return render(request,"login.html")     
    return render(request,"maintenance.html")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add range at the end of the query like `[1-10]` and if you want the first record then just put `[0]` at the end of the query. If you want specific record then put its number at the end of the query like `[5]` or `[3]` etc.

```
duedate=maintanance_table.objects.values_list('maintanance_todate').filter(user_email=abc).order_by('maintanance_todate').reverse()[1-10]

checkstatus=maintanance_table.objects.filter(user_email=abc).filter(maintanance_status="PAID").order_by('maintanance_todate').reverse()[1-10]
```